# ASP Identity, RequireUniqueEmail = true not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I develope ASP.NET MVC5 application (not ASP 5). 
I want to allow users to change email later.
For this cause I do not want user names to be equal to emails.
I do it like this (by generating username):

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = GenerateUserName(), Email = model.Email };
```

At the same time I want emails to be unique, so I set RequireUniqueEmail = true in IdentityConfig.cs:

```
            manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, int>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
```

The question is: **why does UserManager successfully create new user with already existing email (not user name!)?**

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

My guess is, that it checks for UserName uniqueness (which in my case is provided by GenerateUserName() method). If my guess is correct -  RequireUniqueEmail property is mistakingly named so, it probably should be named RequireUniqueUserName. Or there's other reason I don't know of. Please, help.

Comment: Could you provide more code about your custom UserManager you used ? RequireUniqueEmail is not mistakingly named, the goal of this property is to check the uniqueness of Email field. To prove that use DotPeak and browse Microsoft code ;-).

Comment: I didn't change anything. Default User Manager http://pastebin.com/PKhVFtJe

Comment: What is the **UserStoreIntPk** ? It is a custom user store ?

Comment: Yes. I used it to change UserId from Guid to int. http://pastebin.com/udBMeKne

Comment: It is very strange because as you have implemented, the process must be followed the default one as designed by Microsoft. I will try with your code. Could you please provide the ApplicationUser code ?

Comment: Thank you for investigation. ApplicationUser is in last pastebin link.

Comment: Ok, you're welcome. I will try as soon as possible ;-)

Comment: I think this piece of code is somewhy not called: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/e30653c71bbef68be0d8490b43f3cd27cad9c937/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/UserValidator.cs

     var owner = await manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (owner != null && 
                !string.Equals(await manager.GetUserIdAsync(owner), await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user)))
            {
                errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateEmail(email));
            }

Comment: Strange, isn't there an error in ASP code? If User (owner) is created already and has an id, would not it be found by "FindByEmail" method. Thus, owner and user will be equal anyway.

Comment: I found the origin of mistake. It's becouse of Dependency Injection. My unity IOC creates UserManager by constructor, not by Create static method. Thus ignores all options!

Comment: That's why I don't understand :-). Ok could you please edit your post and mark as solution for other people.